# Too long query from table with 200 million rows in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server

I have table1 with 40 columns and 200 million rows (A table that records the history of 200,000 users activities):

```
userid  name    ranking energy     time       ID  ...
--------------------------------------------------- ...  
222     tom      15      f       1657642231    997  
333     sara     11      f       1657642225    996
333     sara     2       a       1657642224    995
111     jhon     4       h       1657642223    994
111     jhon     16      f       1657642222    993
333     sara     13      g       1657642221    992
222     tom      12      j       1657642220    991
```

This table have just 2 columns(userid  ,time) `None-Unique,Non-Clustred` and just 1 column (ID) Clustred-primary key and auto increment.

When I use below  query that take long 10 min:

`select * from table1 where   userid =2323 ORDER BY time`

When I use query select rows with condiotion time for 1 day, for example:

`select * from table1 where time > 1657642220  and userid =2323 ORDER BY time`

or

`select * from table1 where userid =2323 and time  between 1657642220 and 1657728620  ORDER BY time`

That was too long maybe 1 hour or more to return data, but when I copy 4 milion rows from table1 to table 2 and I select the above query from table2 that was very fast 3 sec.
Note: The structure of Table2 is exactly the copy of table1 and 5 million new rows are added to the table1 every day.
Why is the table1 so slow? Should I use a database other than SQL server, such as NOsql? Which database is suitable for this table?

This is Live Query Statistics for table1 for query `select * from table1 where  userid =2323 and time  between 1657642220 and 1657728620 ORDER BY time`:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That plan shows you have a scan of one of your tables; if that's the one with 200M rows (we don't know as you've hidden the names) then that's going to be *slow*. I suggest you post the query you are running, and the DDL of the tables involved (including their indexes).

Comment: and "with condiotion time for 1 day" I guess you need to limit query with where time > 1657642220 and time<....

Comment: @Sergey I limit query with `time between 1657642220  and 1657728620` but too slow yet

Comment: Do you still have a scan when you do that? If so, then it's *still* scanning the **entire** table. A more restrictive `WHERE` won't make a scan faster, because there's only one way to do a scan; read *every single row* in the index/table.

Comment: @Larnu query is `select * from table1 where time > 1657642220  and userid =2323 ORDER BY time`

Comment: What about the DDL of the table and indexes...?

Comment: @henrry May'be stats were outdated. How frequently you update table stats

Comment: @Roshan I never update table stats, Auto Update Statistics is true on my DB

Comment: @henrry Check this. https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-statistics-and-how-to-perform-update-statistics-in-sql/

Comment: Last update was for today an update now  but is slow yet

Comment: Can you post the table DDL? You have a binary column(s) like varchar(max) or varbinary(max) ? Can you post the size (Mb) of the table (you can find it through the reports inside the SSMS)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for query tuning advice, however, does not include the DDL for the objects involved, along with their indexes, and the query plan in a consumable format (such as by using [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)). It therefore lacks the information to be able to performance tune their query.

Comment: select userid,time from table1 where userid=2323 and time between 1657642220  and 1657728620   Could you please try  this and take a look on the execution plan ?

Comment: I update question  with new plan images